# How can I use a MySQL after insert trigger which includes a SELECT and JOIN statement and only copies new entries?

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have an AFTER INSERT trigger which contains a SELECT and JOIN statement, however, when it runs, it pushes all rows, not just the new rows.
I've tried using 'NEW.field_name', but that stops the first table (bib_timing) from being written to.
Below is the trigger which sends all rows to the new table:

```
AFTER INSERT ON `bib_timing`
FOR EACH ROW
INSERT INTO witchfindertrail.comments (name, time_stamp)

SELECT
tl.tag_id,
time_stamp

FROM bib_timing bt

JOIN zd4k_rfid_tag_list tl ON tl.id = bt.name
```

I suspect I cannot use `NEW.tl.tag_id`, but I don't know how to get around this.
I've tried including the Primary Key column (id) as it is an unique and setting this as `NEW.id`, but this did not help.

As a background, this is for timing a running event. The 'rfid_tag_list' table contains the RFID tag numbers and associated runners bib numbers.

The comments table receives and RFID tag number, adds a TIMESTAMP and uses a TIMEDIFF from a pre-set start time for the elapsed time.
The 'bib_entry' table receives the runners bib number and adds a TIMESTAMP, the trigger should join the bib number to the RFID tag number and insert the tag_id and time_stamp into the comments table. This is  for the event of the RFID tag not working/lost/build etc. Marshals can use a web interface to enter the bib number to record their finish time.

It's all going well other than this trigger!

Comment: It's just occurred to me that I don't need the 'time_stamp' within the trigger as the 'comments' table will add this.

Comment: So does that mean the trigger is no longer needed? ... Anyway, the trigger is not possible because the same table cannot be referenced within the trigger's action. (for reading or writing)

Comment: Paul T- Yes, I done things differently so didn't need to rely on a trigger. Thanks for your response though, useful to know.